# Amplify GraphQL API not responding

Tags: javascript, react-native, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Amplify GraphQL on my React Native App just stopped working for no reasons at all. It is stuck on refreshing (trying to query the data). And I made no changed whatsoever to the API. What can I do?

I killed the server severally and restarted it, still stuck on loading. Had to wait 2 days to see if it's coming from Amplify, still no result. I'm considering starting a new project from scratch and then copying and pasting all the code but it will be at the expense of the already existing data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you just send a request to the service via curl?